# jQuery SyntaxError need help to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting this error '**jQuery SyntaxError: missing : after property id**' in all browsers and I am not sure how to fix. I have run the code through lint and I am getting the same error. The offending line is this in the code:

```
$('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {
```

As I am new to jquery/js, I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I have gone wrong. Thanks

jquery code

```
// function to connect to php and process form values

$(function(){
        $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            name: { required: true },
            lname: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            name: { required: "* required" },
            lname: { required: "* required" }
        },
        $('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {

        var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize() + '&submit=' + $(this).val();

         //alert(formdata);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/sample/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
           data: formdata,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(msg){
               if(typeof msg.boxerrortext !== "undefined" && msg.boxerrortext == "You need to input a box")
                   {
                     $("#BA_addbox").html(msg.boxerrortext);
                   }
               else
                   {
                     $("#BA_addbox").html("You have successfully added box " + msg.box + " to the archive.");
                   }
               //$("#confirm_department").hide();

               /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
               //alert(msg);
               //console.log(msg);
               //$("#BA_addbox").html(msg.box);

               //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
               //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
               //$("#boxaddform").hide();
          }
       });
         return false;
     });
   });
});

// end php processing
// End function to submit box intake form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your jquery should be like this:

The listener `$('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function ()` should be independent of the `validate` method.

```
$(function () {
    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            lname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "* required"
            },
            lname: {
                required: "* required"
            }
        },
    });

    $('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {

        var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize() + '&submit=' + $(this).val();

        //alert(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sample/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                if (typeof msg.boxerrortext !== "undefined" && msg.boxerrortext == "You need to input a box") {
                    $("#BA_addbox").html(msg.boxerrortext);
                } else {
                    $("#BA_addbox").html("You have successfully added box " + msg.box + " to the archive.");
                }
                //$("#confirm_department").hide();

                /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
                //alert(msg);
                //console.log(msg);
                //$("#BA_addbox").html(msg.box);

                //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                //$("#boxaddform").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

One more thing.. You need to do because the validate is on the form, and your listener is on the submit button, which wont work:

```
$('#BA_boxform').on('submit', function ()
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it goes straight to the ajax call and doesn't even see the validate function. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 That is because you have the validation on the form submit, and then listening for click on input submit, which is the issue.

Comment: I have changed click to submit and it sees the validation but does not return the json data only refreshes the screen. How do I solve this please. thanks

Comment: Remove the `return false` at the end

Comment: It makes no difference. the boxesadd.php is not even displaying in console when i click the submit button.

Comment: does alert(msg) show anything? Also, see if the URL is actually being hit.

Comment: I have placed code I am currently using at: http://jsfiddle.net/PsaNu/ could you please check if this is correct. Thanks

Comment: what do you get when you do alert(msg) ?

Comment: all the values that are being posted. ie; BA_authorised=Admin. i can also see the values in the post tab of firebug. The funny thing is that when all fields are complete, the boxesadd.php flashes in red in the console then the page refreshes itself and holds the data in the browser cache.

Comment: To avoid refreshing the page change the "submit" button to a "button". That will prevent the refresh. You could also put "return false;" on your method (like you have); you just need to attach the handler to the submit instead of the click.  Since your are returning false to the "click" event and not the submit, you actually don't cancel the submit and it self posts after the click event runs.

Comment: @Dan Kaufman How would I do that Dan, bearing in mind I am still learning jquery. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 - You are bound to get much better responses if you make it a new questions. Your jquery code looks fine. Not sure why it is not working

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, your `$("#BA_boxform").validate()` hasn't been closed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the offending line of code does not have a variable name.  That function is being passed after a comma in a list of "options" or properties.  If that method is supposed to be passed as a eventhandler you would need to do something like:

// function to connect to php and process form values

```
$(function(){
    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: { required: true },
        lname: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        name: { required: "* required" },
        lname: { required: "* required" }
    },
    myEventHandler: $('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {
// rest of code snippet you had
```

That said, I am not sure that is what you are trying to do.  It looks like you are adding a click handler as part of the options to the validate function.  Considering you are calling a line of code and not passing a method handler, I am guessing you meant something like:

```
$(function(){
    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: { required: true },
        lname: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        name: { required: "* required" },
        lname: { required: "* required" }
    }
   }); 
// Validate is ended

// now add your event handler
  $('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {

// rest of code snippet you had
```

---

**Above answered the original question.**  I will attempt to answer the refresh question brought up in the comments of the accepted answer.  Most of my suggestions are based on some assumptions about the html code not shown.

Ok - to stop the refresh there are two easy options.
1. Change the submit button from `<input type='submit'/>` to `<input type='button'/>`
2. Return false (like you are doing) on the click handler (mistake on my comment above).

The possible reasons you are still refreshing after trying #2 is an error in the javascript halting processing.  Change the input type in you html to "button" instead of submit.  Then remove the submit in the jquery selector and reference the button by class or id instead `$('#BA_boxform').find('.classOfYourButton').on('click', function () {`.  This should stop any accidental posting if you don't hit the return false part.

Other than that, I am not sure what the issues are.  As others have said, after correcting the closure of the validate method, the code is correct (although it is not doing what you want).  It would be easier to troubleshoot if you posted them in a new question with other pertinent code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you properly wrote the selector

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
```

because I think it should be only

```
var $dialog = $('#dialog')
```

or if you want to create a new element, use append instead.

Comment: jquery will handle it either way.  It is smart like that.